# Wordpress woocommerce checkout internal server error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

I have Woocommerce in my Wordpress but in my checkout page when placing order I encountered an error says "Internal Server Error", my orders did go through my woocommerce > orders and also my payment successfully did go through my stripe.

I tried some solution I found in some website below but still no luck.

1. I created php.ini in my wp-admin

`memory_limit = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
file_uploads = On`

2. I renamed htaccess then updated the permalink in my wordpress settings but nothing happened.
3. deactivated some of the plugins I installed to try if maybe they are causing the error but that error still appearing.

I just noticed this "Internet Server Error" did appeared when my wordpress version got updated because it was working properly before and I found that my wordpress automatically got updated.

If you have any solution that can help with this problem, I'm glad you could help.

Comment: Can you provide any error logs from the actual error file?

Comment: thank you, I already solved this problem deleting my email template.